# JavaScript: The Good Parts; why is lookahead not good?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm reading Douglas Crockfords [Javascript: The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742), I just finished the regular expressions chapter. In this chapter he calls JavaScript's `\b`, positive lookahead `(?=)` and negative lookahead `(?!)` *"not a good part"*

He explains the reason for `\b` being not good (it uses `\w` for word boundary finding, and `\w` fails for any language that uses unicode characters), and that looks like a very good reason to me.

Unfortunately, the reason for positive and negative lookahead being not good is left out, and I cannot come up with one. [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) showed me the power that comes with lookahead (and of course explains the issues it brings with it), but I can't really think of anything that would qualify it as "not a good part".

**Can anyone explain why JavaScript (positive|negative) lookahead or (positive|negative) lookahead in general should be considered "not good"?**

It seems I'm not the only one with this question: [one](http://jjinux.blogspot.com/2009/03/books-javascript-good-parts-part-2.html) and [two](http://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2009/03/).

Comment: The moment I read that sentence I googled it, and came up with this. Very strange - everything else he says makes perfect sense, and he almost always explains his reasons for saying things are "bad".

Comment: I agree with @Skilldrick. Crockford has been really good at explaining his reasoning for nearly every point he makes in this book, but in this case he doesn't explain anything at all. I too googled after finding no explanation and ended up here. It seems to me like positive/negative lookaheads are awesome as long as you understand how they work and the potentially negative impact they could have on performance if used inappropriately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe it's because of Internet Explorer's [perpetually buggy implementation of lookaheads](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug).  For anyone authoring a book about JavaScript, any feature that doesn't work in IE might as well not exist.

Comment: I don't know what mr Crockford was thinking when he wrote this, but this seems the best reason to be careful with lookahead in javascript. It feels a bit unfair to blame the language for buggy implementations though.

Comment: Remember: JavaScript can be used outside web, as node.js proves!

Comment: Certainly! Remember though, that Javascript: the good parts was written before node.js came along, so this still qualifies as the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

The only reason I can think of might be that they are only supported by about half of the popular regular expression engines, though if you limit yourself to universally supported syntax there are a lot of things you just cannot do.

By the way (positive|negative)(lookahead|lookbehind) is sometimes collectively referred to as "lookaround", as in this page that compares the support of features among various implementations:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Comment: I was thinking in that direction too, but lack of support in general doesn't really qualify it as a bad part of a specific language that actually supports it.

Answer (score 2):

They're too hard for him?

Or: lookaheads and lookbehinds (the latter are not supported in JavaScript) increase regex times considerably. But one isn't typically regexing through huge amounts of data in JavaScript. So they're great; use them when they're useful.

Comment: too hard seems unlikely... performance might be a reason, but that is more of an interpreter issue that could be solved than a language specification issue.

Comment: I wasn't really being serious with the "too hard" bit. But interpreter issues seem like alright reasons to say a language feature ought to be avoided. But, again, I'd disagree with Crockford that there is any kind of issue that would make lookaheads worth avoiding. Lookarounds are fantastic.

Comment: Crockford's a smart guy, and I figure he would know better than anyone why he concluded lookaheads are bad, so I shot him an email. If he replies, I will post it here (if he doesn't do so himself).

Comment: no answer yet I gather? I've tried to contact mr. Crockford as well.