# Replace spaces javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a location to postcode form. The only trouble is the result of the postcode may contain 2 or more spaces. I would like to make sure that there isn't more than one space. In other words >1 space change to 1 space.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showLocation(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            $.getJSON('http://www.uk-postcodes.com/latlng/' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '.json?callback=?', null, gotpostcode);
        }

        function errorHandler(err) {
            if(err.code == 1) {
                alert("Error: Access is denied!");
            } else if( err.code == 2) {
                alert("Error: Position is unavailable!");
            }
        }


        function gotpostcode(result)
        {
            var postcode = result.postcode;
            $("#postcodegoeshere").val(postcode);
        }

        function getLocation(){
            if(navigator.geolocation){
                // timeout at 60000 milliseconds (60 seconds)
                var options = {timeout:60000};
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showLocation, 
                                                         errorHandler,
                                                         options);
            } else {
                alert("Sorry, browser does not support geolocation!");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" onclick="getLocation();"  
                                 value="Get Location"/>
        </form>
        <div>
            <input id='postcodegoeshere' name='xxx' type='text' value='' />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635952/javascript-how-to-remove-all-extra-spacing-between-words

Comment: How about leading/trailing spaces: is `" foobar "` ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex and replace `/[ ]+/g` with a space.

```
var str = "this     has    a lot of     whitespaces";
var str = str.replace(/[ ]+/g, " ");
console.log(str); 
//this has a lot of whitespaces
```

Regex explanation:

- `[ ]` the character "space" enclosed in brackets for readability - you don't need them.
- `+` repeated 1 or more times
- `/g` not just once, but globally in the whole string

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
str = str.replace(/ {2,}/g, ' ');
```

Comment: Technically `\s` would replace a tab character followed by a newline followed by a space etc., so not just a space as the OP wants.

Comment: Yep, that should be what OP wants. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace ( "  " , " " , $string )
```

Comment: 1. This is PHP - 2. This would turn `my string[SPACE][SPACE][SPACE][SPACE]hey` into `my string[SPACE][SPACE]he`, so it doesn't work as well as `preg_replace("/[ ]+/", " ", $string)` would.