# whitespace before or after characters, symbols, or numbers; but, not in-between

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I'm trying to write a regexp that selects whitespace before or after any character( letters, symbols, or numbers ), but not in-between words composed of the characters.

For example, in `'      abc'`, the spaces before would match; but, in `'words words  words'` none of the whitespace in-between would be selected.

So in `'   hello world  to    everyone         '`, only the leading and trailing whitespace would be selected.

Bonus: if there's a way to separately, in a second regexp, select the white-space in-between, that would help alot.

What i'm trying to do is, in javascript, minimise the whitespace in a sentence so that leading and trailing whitespace is gone and the white-space in-between words is shrunk to 1 space.

Comment: But `"hello world  to    everyone"` has no leading/trailing space?

Comment: I added some quotation marks to keep the whitespace from collapsing.

Comment: `String#trim()` should already do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635952/javascript-how-to-remove-all-extra-spacing-between-words)**

```
var string = "    hello world     to       everyone. ";
string = string.trim().replace(/\s+/g, " ");
alert(string);
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4aou5cj/3/)**

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem and not just giving me the easiest solution. I didn't know there was a trim method. I'll look into that some more.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to make multi-space to be one-space ? Just do :

```
var text="hello world  to    everyone";
text=text.trim().replace(/\s+/g," ");

document.write(text); // It will print 'hello world everyone'
```

Comment: It prints `helloworldeveryone`

Comment: The replacement value should have been a single space, I fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Through regex and regex only**

You could do this through regex without using any js inbuilt functions like `trim()`

```
> var s = '    hello    world   to    everyone   '
> s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s*(\s)/g, "$1")
'hello world to everyone'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rZ2uV3/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^\s+` Matches the leading one or more spaces.
- `|` OR
- `\s+$` Matches the trailing spaces.
- `|` OR
- `\s*(\s)` From the remaining string, this regex would match zero or more spaces and captures the last space. So the captured group that is, group index 1 a single space.
- Replacing all the matched spaces with the space present inside the group index 1 will give you the desired output.

Comment: or `^\s+|\s+$|\s+(\s)`

Comment: I find the other answer more readable, especially if I think of maintainability.