# Removing additional spaces between words in a <textarea> dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

Is it possible, within the following fiddle, to add a space between each word once the text has been extracted dynamically and change the text within the `<textarea>` automatically, not requiring a button?

Attached is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afy5v66x/1/)

HTML:

```
<textarea rows='5' cols='50' id='content'></textarea>
```

JQuery:

```
 function someFunction() {
 var output = document.getElementById("content").value;
 output = output.replace(/\s/g, "");
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
```

}

An updated fiddle would be very much appreciated, as I am still new to coding.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

if the textarea id is "input",

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#input").keyup(function(){
        var textarea = $("#input");
        var str = textarea.text();
        str = str.replace(/\s\s+/gi, ' ');
        textarea.text(str);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript trim method as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635952/javascript-how-to-remove-all-extra-spacing-between-words).

Sample:

```
<textarea id="test">Lorem     [remove this space and other spaces dynamically]      ipsum dolor sit amet,        [remove this space]              consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet pharetra erat sed.
</textarea>
<script>
  ar = document.getElementById('test').value;
  string = ar.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
  document.getElementById('test').value=ar;
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Note: I hadn't tested but my example actually gives you hint how to achieve this.